# sort larger javascript array by another array and move values to the top of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I apologize if this has been asked before but I was looking to sort a javascript array based on the criteria of another array. I know that all of the values contained in the criteria array will be in the larger array somewhere but I need the ones from the criteria array to be moved to the top of the list.

For example I have a larger array that looks something like this :

```
array = [
  {_id: "123", username: "username1",platform: "xbox"},
  {_id: "124", username: "username2",platform: "xbox"},
  {_id: "125", username: "username3",platform: "ps4"},
  {_id: "126", username: "username4",platform: "pc"},
  {_id: "127", username: "username5",platform: "ps4"},
  {_id: "128", username: "username6",platform: "pc"}
    ];
```

I then need to sort this larger array based on the criteria of the smaller array and then move those values to the top of the larger one

So in this case the criteria array would be

```
critarray = [
 {_id: "124", username: "username2",platform: "xbox"},
 {_id: "127", username: "username5",platform: "ps4"},
 {_id: "128", username: "username6",platform: "pc"},
];
```

The the larger array would be sorted as follows:

```
array = [
  {_id: "124", username: "username2",platform: "xbox"},
  {_id: "127", username: "username5",platform: "ps4"},
  {_id: "128", username: "username6",platform: "pc"},
  {_id: "123", username: "username1",platform: "xbox"},
  {_id: "125", username: "username3",platform: "ps4"},
  {_id: "126", username: "username4",platform: "pc"},
    ];
```

Also it doesn't really matter the order as long as all the objects in the criteria array are moved to the top.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Filter and concat**

Since you don't care about the order other than these two groups and you know the larger array has all the elements from the smaller, rather than sorting, you could just filter all `critarray` items out of `array` than concatenate `critarray` and `array`:

```js
let array = [
    {_id: "123", username: "username1",platform: "xbox"},
    {_id: "124", username: "username2",platform: "xbox"},
    {_id: "125", username: "username3",platform: "ps4"},
    {_id: "126", username: "username4",platform: "pc"},
    {_id: "127", username: "username5",platform: "ps4"},
    {_id: "128", username: "username6",platform: "pc"}
      ];

let  critarray = [
   {_id: "124", username: "username2",platform: "xbox"},
   {_id: "127", username: "username5",platform: "ps4"},
   {_id: "128", username: "username6",platform: "pc"},
  ];

// all items not in crit array
let arrayFiltered = array.filter(item => !critarray.find(i => i._id === item._id) )

// concat critarray first, then rest
let newArr = critarray.concat(arrayFiltered)

console.log(newArr)
```

This assumes `_id` is a unique identifier.

**or Sort**

Alternatively, you could also make a `Set` of ids from `citarray` and use inclusion in that set as the basis for sorting if you want to sort the array in place:

```js
let array = [
    {_id: "123", username: "username1",platform: "xbox"},
    {_id: "124", username: "username2",platform: "xbox"},
    {_id: "125", username: "username3",platform: "ps4"},
    {_id: "126", username: "username4",platform: "pc"},
    {_id: "127", username: "username5",platform: "ps4"},
    {_id: "128", username: "username6",platform: "pc"},
      ];

let  critarray = [
   {_id: "124", username: "username2",platform: "xbox"},
   {_id: "127", username: "username5",platform: "ps4"},
   {_id: "128", username: "username6",platform: "pc"},
  ];

let critIds = new Set
critarray.forEach(item => critIds.add(item._id))

array.sort((a, b) => critIds.has(b._id) - critIds.has(a._id))
console.log(array)
```